# Linear Mixed Model Looking for significant effects

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

Hello I'm currently doing data analysis of my study in R.

I'm having trouble with finding the right way to go about it though.

Snippet of my data:

```
tibble [42 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ FP_Nummer: int [1:42] 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Koen     : Factor w/ 3 levels "","K","M": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ maaling  : chr [1:42] "T1" "T2" "T3" "T4" ...
 $ VO2max   : int [1:42] 3085 3474 3920 4078 4364 4363 3470 3516 3679 4026 ...
 $ BV       : int [1:42] 5332 5808 6823 5808 6542 6093 4851 4691 5093 5241 ...
```

I want to analyse wether BV has a significant impact on VO2max. I have 6 different measurement times (maaling) then i have a subject ID (FP_Nummer) and gender (Koen)

I've tried using LM4 for linear mixed model analysis to account for the interaction that Subject ID has but I'm really not sure if im doing it right.

They are measured at the study participation intervals which is determined as certain lengths of time since the subject joined the study. They principally reflect the same "time" as all subjets were measured at the 6 month interval etc.

However I dont really see how it determines that the correlation between VO2max and BV is negative since both increases from start to finish?

I feel i've done something wrong. Maybe I'm just intepreting the data in the wrong way? I assume that the fixed effects with maalingTx says that the estimated difference between Vo2max at intercept and lets say T2 is 114?

Current code:

```
model <- lmer(VO2max ~ BV + maaling + Koen + (1|FP_Nummer), df)
```

My data is arranged in a long format atm.
Summary of data:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  FP_Nummer Koen  maaling VO2max    BV
      <int> <fct> <chr>    <int> <int>
1         4 M     T1        3085  5332
2         4 M     T2        3474  5808
3         4 M     T3        3920  6823
4         4 M     T4        4078  5808
5         4 M     T5        4364  6542
6         4 M     T6        4363  6093
```

So my hope is that i can explain VO2max from BV while accounting for the different measurement times and the effect of Koen and random effect of FP_Nummer. Currently my summary of the model looks like this.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: VO2max ~ BV + maaling + Koen + (1 | FP_Nummer)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 484.9

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.11674 -0.41870  0.02518  0.47079  1.88158 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 FP_Nummer (Intercept) 136038   368.8   
 Residual               23085   151.9   
Number of obs: 42, groups:  FP_Nummer, 7

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 1126.69189  415.64317   2.711
BV             0.21131    0.09055   2.334
maalingT2    114.88897   82.81548   1.387
maalingT3    248.25380   89.75485   2.766
maalingT4    450.77416   82.86137   5.440
maalingT5    554.10856   91.80413   6.036
maalingT6    606.48771   86.39924   7.020
KoenM       1523.96514  327.50548   4.653

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr) BV     mlngT2 mlngT3 mlngT4 mlngT5 mlngT6
BV        -0.884                                          
maalingT2  0.077 -0.196                                   
maalingT3  0.288 -0.426  0.527                            
maalingT4  0.080 -0.198  0.519  0.528                     
maalingT5  0.326 -0.466  0.525  0.599  0.526              
maalingT6  0.210 -0.341  0.528  0.571  0.528  0.575       
KoenM      0.176 -0.489  0.096  0.208  0.097  0.228  0.167
fit warnings:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

Can anyone help me out here??

Comment: Velkommen til cv, Rasmus. What makes that you are in doubt of your analysis: is it the warning? And another question: Did you make measurements at the same times for all individuals, or are these just repeated measurements?

Comment: They are measured at the studyparticipation intervals which is determined as certain lengths of time since study start. They principally reflect the same "time" as all subjets were measured at the 6 month interval etc. 

However I dont really see how it determines that the correlation between VO2max and BV is negative since both increases from start to finish?

I feel i've done something wrong. Maybe I'm just intepreting the data in the wrong way? 

I assume that the fixed effects with maalingTx says that the estimated difference between Vo2max at intercept and lets say T2 is 114?

Comment: you are having some very concrete questions - it would be helpful for any potential answerers to see these question inside your question, because they will probably not read the comments. The effect of the times is nicely increasing, I did not see this when I asked about them, sorry :-)

It could also be nice if you give a bit background on the nature of the data - whatever VO2max (maksimalt oxigen volume?) and BV is. This helps guessing what is going on if it is weird at all.

Comment: > However I dont really see how it determines that the correlation between VO2max and BV is negative since both increases from start to finish? 
This could be due to the fact that time alone explains almost everything.

Comment: This is what confuses me aswell! i will add my questions to the post - is there any more information that i can provide to help with the question?

Comment: I think you are getting there - here are two more suggestions: 1) It would help to know what VO2max and BV is, roughly - can you disclose the scientific question? 2) Do the time intervals have the same length? The effect of time seems nicely increasing, so one could perhaps use this in the model.